# Haskell modified hamming so that the input is a list instead of 1

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

So this would be the standard hamming code for Haskell, I managed to understand and write it.

```
merge :: Ord a =>[a] -> [a] -> [a] 
merge [] ys = ys
merge xs [] = xs
merge (x : xs) (y : ys) 
    | x == y    = x : merge xs ys
    | x < y     = x : merge xs (y : ys)
    | otherwise = y : merge (x:xs) ys

hamming :: [Integer]
hamming = 1: merge (map (2 *) hamming)
                  (merge (map (3 *) hamming)
                         (map (5 *) hamming))
```

Now i'm trying to create a modified hamming code which has a list as input ( instead of 1 like in the standard hamming code ) .

Example would be  print take 10 modifiedhamming [10,30,50]  with the output [10,20,30,40,50,60,80,90,100, 120] . Sadly i can't manage to make it generate next elements after it multiplies the initial list with 2, 3 and 5.

This is what I tried :

```
hammingCode :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
hammingCode a  =    merge    ( map (*2) a)
                             (merge (map (*3) a)
                                    (merge a (map (*5) a)))

main = print (take 20 (hammingCode [10, 20, 50]))
```

with the output : [10,20,30,40,50,60,100,150,250] . As stated before this will just multiply the initial list with each element

I also tried this but i get a stack overflow error

```
hammingCode2 xs = merge xs (merge (map (*2) hammings) (merge (map (*3) hammings) (map (*5) hammings)))
  where
    hammings = hammingCode2 xs
```

I've tried solving this by reading through different functional programming books and even with chatgpt and bard and still didn't manage to solve it .

Comment: What is the correct output that you expect? you could try `main = print (take 20 (concatMap hammingCode [[10], [20], [50]]))`, does this go in the correct direction?

Comment: @Caridorc  this would be the exact text of the exercise : generalise the Hamming problem by replacing 1 with a
list bs of positive numbers sorted in ascending order. That is, we now wish
to find a list in ascending order such that every b in bs is in the list, and if
x is in the list then 2x, 3x and 5x are in the list. And this is an example main = print take 10 modifiedhamming [10,30,50] with the output [10,20,30,40,50,60,80,90,100, 120]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: a modest change to your `hamming` function would allow you to generate a list of all needed multiples starting with any single `Integer`:

```
hamming2 :: Integer -> [Integer]
hamming2 x = ham
  where ham = x : merge (map (2 *) ham)
                      (merge (map (3 *) ham)
                             (map (5 *) ham))
```

If you were to `map hamming2` over a list like `[10,30,50]`, that would give you a list of three lists that can be `merge`d together to get all of the required multiples.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Finally i managed to get to the solution. I just needed to merge all the lists with foldr after creating the map hamming2 you told me about. You made my day